# leading optional path parameters in React Router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In v5 I use next path regex:

`/:locale?/:city?/mobile`

In v6 it doesn't work. Tried to use array in `path` prop, but it doesn't supported

How I can refactor these in v6?

Answer (score 1):

See this Github issue: https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/7285

React Router v6 apparently doesn't support optional params anymore. Instead, you need to create a route per combination of params. In your case I think it may look something like this:

```jsx
<Route path="/:locale">
    <Route path="/:city" element={<Page />} />
    <Route path="" element={<Page />} />
</Route>
<Route path="/:mobile" element={<Page />} />
```

Comment: I describe one route for example, in fact there are many routes

Comment: This same pattern would need to be followed for any routes with optional params.